# jinja2 comment out (disable) code blocks with nested comments

Tags: jinja2

Trying to figure out the best way to comment out blocks of jinja2 code that may contain other comments... e.g. this:

```
{# 
    {# Start Config #}
    something
    something else
    {{ some_var }}
    {% for for in bar %}
    {{ foo }}
#}
```

The issue seems to be that because i have `{# Start Config #}`
the `{#` and `#}` don't seem to be working correctly e.g. looking in my sublime text editor none of the text under  `{# Start Config #}` is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enclose it in a *comment* block.

```
{% comment %}
..
..
{% endcomment %}
```